# Read all bytes from socket Stops at 52964 bytes

Tags: java, c, sockets, ansi-c

I'm making a Server that gets packages at 64 kb size.

```
        int length = 65536;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

        int pos = 0;
        while(pos < length -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Before read");
            pos += dis.read(bytes, pos, length-pos);
            System.out.println(""+pos+" >> "+ length);
        }
```

This is the code I use to read all bytes from the socket. `Dis` is a `InputStream`. 
When I run the code 1 out of n goes wrong. The code only receives 52964 bytes instead of `65536` bytes.

I also checked the C code and it says it send `65536` bytes.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have sender side code?

Comment: I don't see how this happens as you are not getting `-1` for EOF either I assume. What are you getting, an Exception?

Comment: Did you set the size of the socket's receive buffer?

Comment: Not the main problem, but your loop skips the last byte, use `while(pos < length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is yet another case where [Jakarta Commons IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) is a better choice than writing it yourself. It's one line of code, and it's fully tested. I recommend `IOUtils.readFully()` in this case.

If it does not read the entire buffer, then you know that you're not sending all the content. Perhaps you're missing a flush on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

`InputStream.read()` returns the number of bytes read or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached. You need to check for that error condition. Also, I suspect your `while(..)` loop is the problem. Why are you calling it `pos` as in position? You may be terminating prematurely. Also, ensure that your C code, whatever it is doing, is sending properly. You can examine the network traffic with a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it "goes wrong"? What is the output? It can't be exiting the loop before reading the full 64 KB, so what really happens?

Also, it's better to save the return value of the I/O call separately and inspect it, before assuming the I/O was successful. If that's `DataInputStream.read()`, it returns -1 on error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect as it doesn't check for -1.

This is a case for using DataInputStream.readFully() rather than coding it yourself and getting it wrong.